# 2008r2 nslookup returns Non-existent domain

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2

I need to create a self-contained windows LAN on a couple of VMs.

I have a couple of hyper-v VMs running Windows 2008r2 on a Win8 host.

Both VMs are running off the same virtual switch which is attached to the Ethernet port of the host laptop.

Here's what I've done so far:

- allocated a fixed IP address to VM1
- promoted VM1 to be a domain controller using dcpromo.
- set the primary dns of VM2 to IP address of VM1
- from VM2 joined the domain created on VM1

When I run nslookup from VM2 it is able to resolve to VM1. However, when I try the reverse from VM1 I get the message:"localhost can't find 2008r2server2: Non-existent domain"

Could anyone please help troubleshoot?

Thanks
Rob.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should probably be a comment but alas, not enough rep... Are you using the nslookup query with the fqdn? If not I would suggest looking at the dns suffix, making sure it's correct.

Comment: yes, just tried it with nslookup WIN2008R2SVR2.biztalkers.lab but I got the message: Server: UnKnown Address: 192.168.1.200 (this the ip of the PDC) ***UnKnown can't find WIN2008R2SVR2: Non-existent domain. When I look in "Active directory Users and Computers" on the PDC I can see WIN2008R2SVR2 listed in the "Computers" folder. When I double-click this it shows the DNS name as "2008r2server2.biztalkers.lab"

Comment: Have you configured the reverse zone for your DNS?